# Python : Create a "blurry gif" from original gif

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, blurry

I am looking for a smart way to create a blurry gif from a gif.

Currently I have a script to do the same for jpeg / png :

```
blurry_image = Image.open(file).filter(ImageFilter.BoxBlur(50))
blurry_output = io.BytesIO()
blurry_image.save(blurry_output, format=image_format)
```

but this script does not work for gif, is there an easy way to do that in python ?

Thanks

Comment: You can start here: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4544#issuecomment-612280390 to get out the frames, blur them individually, then put them back into a gif

Comment: Thanks, I will test that and post my code if it is working

Comment: “does not work for gif” — please elaborate on the issue. What happens? Is the output wrong? Do you get an error message? And be specific!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Marcel, I succeed to do the work by looping over frames

```
    im = Image.open(file)
    frames = [np.asarray(im_frame.convert('RGB').filter(ImageFilter.BoxBlur(50)))
              for im_frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(im)]
    blurry_images = [Image.fromarray(a_frame) for a_frame in np.stack(frames)]

    blurry_images[0].save(blurry_output, save_all=True, append_images=blurry_images[1:], format='gif', loop=0)
```

I don't know if there is already a library to do it directly, but here it is working
Basically, it saves all the frame in PNG format image (with blurry option), and rebuild the gif from all these frames saved